# C++ Templates: Byval/Reference interfering with eachother

Tags: c++, templates

Here's a simplified version of my problem. I have a property class. It has data like has_initalized and such which i removed for this example.

When i call a function which uses T its fine. However T& isnt so i decided to write a T& version of it. But this causes all functions which uses plain T to get a compile error. Why is T& interfering with that? For this example how do i get both functions (Q and W) to work without changing main()?

```
template <class T>
class Property {
    T v;
    Property(Property&p) { }
public:
    Property() {}
    T operator=(T src) { v = src; return v; }
    operator T() const { return v; }
    operator T&() const{ return v; }
    T operator->() { return v; }
};

class A{};

void Q(A  s){}
void W(A& s){}

int main(){
    Property<A> a;
    Q(a);
    W(a);
}
```

Comment: Seriously, I can't understand the question, and the problem.

Comment: @Nawaz: Try compiling it

Comment: -1 for telling me to `Try compiling it`. Why should I? Can't you tell us the error and problem yourself?

Comment: What is the point of this code? Why would you write this to begin with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing in the overloading rules of C++ which allows the compiler to choose between `operatorT()` and `operatorT&()` in the call to Q. So removing the

```
operator T() const { return v; }
```

will also remove the ambiguity.  But then you'll have a problem because returning a non const reference to a member in a const function is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

For your `Q`, you can use both conversion functions. You can make the compiler prefer one over the other by making one non-const.

```
operator T() const { return v; }
operator T&() { return v; }
```

Now for `Q`, the `operator T&` is taken. This way will also fix the call to `W` to get a non-const reference. You can also return a const reference from the other

```
operator T const&() const { return v; }
operator T&() { return v; }
```

This way will still prefer the second conversion function for `Q`, but if your object `a` is const and you initialize a const reference, you won't always require to copy `v`.